# How to add GestureRecognizer for UITableView, but only on empty place?

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add tap - hide table + some actions - named `cancelTap`

I have an `UITableView` and i want to add `cancelTap` for it, **but only at empty place**.
Table height is 200.
Cells fill only a half of table, and on other half (half without cells) i need to add addGestureRecognizer.

If i'm add GestureRecognizer to Table - method `DidSelectCellForRowAtIndexPath` does not respond.
Is it any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just add tap to the `tableView` and in the delegate of the `Tap` set method -

```
(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return _searchDisplayController.contentSize.height <= [touch locationInView:_searchDisplayController].y;
}
```

in this method i deside do i need to apply tap or i ned to ignore it.

Comment: Excellent solution! Just remember to set the delegate on the UIGestureRecognizer or this method won't be called.